# Redefining color values in consumer projects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, reusability

What is the correct way of overriding color resources defined in WPF Controls Library project?

Say I have project A that is a WPF Controls Library having the following two color resources defined:

```
<Color x:Key="Color1">WhiteSmoke</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color2">LightGray</Color>
```

and a Brush created from these colors:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type local:MyControl}, MyControlBackground}">
  <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource Color1}" />
  <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{StaticResource Color2}"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

One of the controls defined in the library uses this brush resource like this:

```
<UserControl>
  <TabControl SelectedIndex="0">
    <TabItem Header="Information">
      <Grid>
      ...
      <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
        ...
          <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey {x:Type local:MyControl}, MyControlBackground}}" />
          ...
```

So far so good. Now project B (a WPF application) and project C (a Visual Studio extension) need to use this control. Both are referencing project A. The only issue is that these two projects need to define different brushes for the control background.

How should I achieve this? Is there a way to redefine `Color1` and `Color2` in consumer projects B and C? Obviously I cannot do this by accessing the `Rectangle` (it is so deep down the hierarchy). Also I cannot use a `Style` here, since there could be other `Rectangle`s in the hierarchy.

What's my way out?

Comment: Color1 and Color2 could be dependency properties of your UserControl.

Comment: Still searching a solution for that or my answer to your other question solves this too?

Comment: @Evk: I ended up implementing it through public properties in my controls that can be set from each consumer project, as suggested by Clemens above. Works, but can quickly become a whole lot of work seeing that there are sooo many things we want to apply themes to.

Comment: So you can use dynamic resource like this `<GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource Color1}" />` and then change colors at runtime like this `Resources["Color1"] = Colors.Yellow` where `Resources` is resource dictionary where your colors are placed. Seems fine enough.

Comment: You can also define "theme" in separate resource dictionary and merge in runtime. Or you can use real WPF themes (it has built-in support for themes after all).

Comment: @Evk: Yep, that was my original thought. It should work the way those built-in themes work. `DynamicResource` seems fair enough, except for the designer support (XAML designer keeps giving error messages for them even when the program actually compiles and works).

Comment: @Evk: Do you see any XAML-only way of doing this?

Comment: I think all resources that could be changed should be stored in one resource dictionary. So you have two resource dictionaries: one for WPF app and another for extension. Then you just merge one or another to your Application resources (in app xaml) using `<ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionary.xaml" />` That's actually how themes work as far as I know.