# How to add more resources to a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

Can we add new resources to a `UserControl` at the point of usage, without wiping out the resources that `UserControl` has defined itself?

So for exmaple, here is a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <!--Resource1-->
    <!--Resource2-->
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

I use this control in the `MainWindow`:

```
<MainWindow>
  <local:MyControl>
    <local:MyControl.Resources>
      <!--Resource3-->
    </local:MyControl.Resources>
  </local:MyControl>
</MainWindow>
```

Doing this wipes out Resource1 and Resource2 and I'm left with Resource3 only. I have tried `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` too, that also has the same effect. I'm looking for a way for Resource3 to *add* to the existing resources list.

Comment: Resource3 should probably be in Window.Resources.

Comment: @Clemens: I tried that too. Problem is that I need to *override* (so to speak) the definition of a particular resource defined in the `UserControl`. This only works if I place my new resource in `MyControl.Resources` section. Putting it anywhere else seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Clemens: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858662/redefining-color-values-in-consumer-projects) shows the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in possibility to do that, as far as I know. But you can do that either via code, or with attached property. For example, let's define such property:

```
public static class ResourceExtensions {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AdditionalResourcesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AdditionalResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary), typeof(ResourceExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnAdditionalResourcesChanged));

    private static void OnAdditionalResourcesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe == null)
            throw new Exception("Cannot add resources to type " + d.GetType());
        if (fe.Resources == null)
            fe.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        var dict = e.NewValue as ResourceDictionary;
        if (dict != null) {                                
            foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in dict) {
                fe.Resources[resource.Key] = resource.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SetAdditionalResources(DependencyObject element, ResourceDictionary value) {
        element.SetValue(AdditionalResourcesProperty, value);
    }

    public static ResourceDictionary GetAdditionalResources(DependencyObject element) {
        return (ResourceDictionary) element.GetValue(AdditionalResourcesProperty);
    }
}
```

What it will do is take resource dictionary and copy all values from it to the resource dictionary of target control (overriding values of existing resources). Usage is:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- This is resource dictionary to merge with target -->
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="overrideResources">
            <Brush x:Key="foreground">Yellow</Brush>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<wpfApplication1:UserControl1 wpfApplication1:ResourceExtensions.AdditionalResources="{StaticResource overrideResources}"/>
```

Note that for it to help with your another question you linked in comments - you need to use resources using `DynamicResource` extension, not `StaticResource`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Brush x:Key="foreground">Red</Brush>
    <Style x:Key="test" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <!-- Note DynamicResource here -->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource foreground}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="test" FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource test}" />
</StackPanel>
```

If I apply the above method with attached property to this `UserControl` - text inside it will become yellow (was red), because `Brush` with key `foreground` was overriden but `Style` with key `test` was left intact, and I used `DynamicResource`. If I used `StaticResource` instead - resources in resource dictionary will still change, but control will not reflect that change, because with `StaticResource` it does not watch for changes in the resource.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the only way out for now. I'm accepting your answer. Will review if we get anything better.

Comment: Note that from code it's easier than from xaml. From code you just do 'yourControl.Resources["Color1"] = Color.White' and done. But using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource is relevant even then.